# Amchart add arrow to force directed chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts

https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-tree/

Here is amchart force-directed-tree chart.
And there is links between charts.
Is there any way to add arrow to the links to understand the links ?

Comment: Sorry again, for what happened below with an angry user... But because of this, maybe no one dares to to tell you that your question does no meet SO guidelines. We need some code to help you. Please have a look at [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Unfortunately adding arrows is not supported at this time: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2020#issuecomment-572248337